# signer information does not match signer information Bouncycastle and jboss

Tags: java, jboss, itext, bouncycastle

I have a problem when I try to sign my pdf document, I'm using a keystore to sign but I change it many times and now `jboss` show me this message

> Failed to define class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier in
>   Module "xx.earxx.war:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: class
>   "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does
>   not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Please I need help, I can't understand the problem!

Comment: that sounds like you have multiple versions of bouncy castle in your class path.

Comment: I agree with mkl. If you use Maven then show us all of your dependencies in your pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks I clean my pom but now I have a new problem, i dont know why but the server's log tell me: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKDigestSignature, and when I try to change the version tell me this Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/digest/MD2$Digest ... Im working with Red Hat 5.5, Jdk 1.8 and jboss eap 6.4